# How to check if an object is a class or an instance of that class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This seems pretty simple, but I can't seem to find anything about it online anywhere.

What I'd like to do is given an object, I need to be able to tell if it's the class itself, or an instance of that class.

In other words:

```
class Test:
  pass

u = Test

check(u) # returns False

i = Test()

check(i) # returns True
```

Note that `u` is just the naked class object, while `i` is an instance of that class.

How do I implement the `check()` function?

Comment: Do you want to only check for instance of a class, or for both the class itself, and the instance of a class @Soviero

Answer (score 0):

We can compare the object with the class itself, to check if it a class, and use [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check if it an instance of the class.

So the code would look like

```
def check(obj, cls):

    if obj is cls:
        print('obj is class')

    elif isinstance(obj, cls):
        print('obj is instance of class')

class Test:
  pass

u = Test
check(u,Test)

i = Test()
check(i, Test)
```

The output will be

```
obj is class
obj is instance of class
```

Note that here we compare the object with that specific class, we can also check if the object is a class via [inspect.isclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isclass)

```
In [28]: u = Test                                                                                                                                            
In [29]: i = Test()                                                                                                                                          

In [30]: inspect.isclass(u)                                                                                                                                  
Out[30]: True

In [32]: inspect.isclass(i)                                                                                                                                  
Out[32]: False
```

Comment: There is no need for `if obj is cls:` - simply `if isinstance(obj, cls):` will do the trick.  if you have a derived class from `Test` this will fail as `isinstance(TestDerived(),Test)` is `True` as well though